# Як перекласти «Rule of thumb»

Tags: переклад, from-english, фразеологізми

- Відповідна стаття у вікіпедії називається *[Емпіричне правило](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE)*:

  > *Емпіричне правило — це широко використовуваний принцип, що не має на меті бути повністю точним для будь-якої ситуації. Це проста у вивченні та застосуванні процедура для обчислення чи пригадування певного значення.*
- Перекладач Google дає *практичне правило*.
- [e2u](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=thumb&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on) - практичне (приблизне, грубе) правило, ме́тод спроб і по́ми́лок, куста́рний спо́сіб.

Вважається, що англійський вираз, який дослівно перекладається як *правило кавурника*, походить від звички майстрів використовувати для вимірів ширину свого великого пальця замість точних інструментів.

Чи є якійсь фразеологізм для цього виразу?

Comment: Чесно кажучи з (цілком правильного) означення не зовсім зрозуміло що воно таке. Зазвичай Rule of thumb це правило (принцип), який дозволяє новачку у якійсь справі досягати непоганих результатів у більшості випадків. Наприклад: "на екзамені краще починати з простих задач, а складні залишати наостанок". Або "у бейсболі спочатку краще виставляти сильних гравців" (приклад з [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/rule-of-thumb?s=t)).

Answer (score 2):

Переглянувши багато прикладів вживання "Rule of a thumb" в [англійських](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/rule-of-thumb) [словниках](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/rule-of-thumb?s=t) мені спало на думку що у більшості випадків для перекладу достатньо слова "[зазвичай](https://onlinecorrector.com.ua/uk/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE/)":

> - A good rule of thumb is that a broker must generate sales of ten times his salary.
> - As a rule of thumb, a cup of filter coffee contains about 80mg of caffeine.
> - The general rule of thumb is that most pilots fly solo for an hour.
> - When playing baseball, a good rule of thumb is to put your best hitter fourth in the batting order.

Ці фрази можна перекласти як:

- Зазвичай брокер має продавати в 10 разів більше своєї зарплати.
- Зазвичай у чашці кави міститься 80 мг кофеїну.
- Зазвичай більшість пілотів літають самостійно протягом години.
- Під час гри у бейсбол зазвичай краще ставити кращого гравця першим у черзі на відбивання.

Але є фрази де "зазвичай" не підходить. Це речення подається як приклад у якому протиставляєтся дія з практичного досвіду та точні критерії ("A rough and useful principle or method, based on experience rather than precisely accurate measures."):

> - His work with the youth group is largely by rule of thumb.

Що можна перекласти як:

- У своїй роботі з молодіжною групою він у першу чергу керується власним досвідом.

Ще приклади, де Rule of thumb виступає як певне правило:

> - He understood the principles of piano construction, and was, therefore, no rule-of-thumb man.
> - Rule-of-thumb can never again overcome the rules of averages, of percentages or of economic laws.
> - All the power of his intelligence, all the rule-of-thumb derived from his practice, is devoted to this alone.
> - Folks got to know, by a sort of rule-of-thumb, truths which scientifically they were unable to learn.

Приблизний переклад:

- Він зрозумів принципи побудови піаніно і був, таким чином, не кустарем.
- Власний досвід ніколи не зможе перемогти правила засновані на середніх значеннях, відсотках та на економічних законах.
- Усю силу свого розуму, весь досвід, що він отримав зі своєї практики - все це він присвячує лише одній справі*.
- Люди мають зрозуміти, з певного практичного досвіду, ті істини, які вони не змогли вивчити за допомогою науки.

<sub>* у більш ширшому [контексті](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/29184/29184-h/29184-h.htm) зрозуміло що йдеться про майстра, який випалює кераміку у печі, все життя займається тільки цим, і всю свою майстерність використовує щоб отримати правильні кольори глазурі.</sub>

Comment: «Rule-of-thumb can never again overcome…» — тут мені чомусь схотілося сказати «_емпірика_ ніколи не зможе…» (хоча я не певен, що я правильно втулив слово).

Comment: Можливо - я тому і написав що переклад приблизний. На мій погляд смисл цього речення приблизно такий: "Оцінка "на око" вже ніколи не переможе правила засновані на точних математичних формулах".

Answer (score 1):

(Не відповідь на ваше питання, але забагато, як для коментаря.)

"Rule of thumb" можна перекласти і без допомоги фразеологізмів. Наприклад, у фізиці використовується таке поняття, як ["правило правої руки"](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%97_%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8): це метод, за допомогою якого простими діями можна визначити напрям силових ліній магнітного поля. Крім того, є багато інших методів, що пропонують прості алгоритми для вирішення геть непростих питань, і кожен має свою назву: ["правило свердлика"](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0) тощо. З огляду на це досить розумним рішенням може бути введення нового терміна, якщо це дозволяє контекст. Наприклад, при перекладі художнього твору або при написанні технічної літератури. Крім того, подібні речі звуться "мнемонікою" або "мнемонічними правилами".

Comment: Тобто Ваша пропозиція полягає в тому, щоб застосовувати для кожного правила окрему назву (а не намагатися охарактеризувати відразу всі емпіричні правила якимось словосполученням), — я правильно розумію?

Comment: @Sasha "правило свердлика" часто застосовують як загальний вислів-відповідник  до rule of thumb з мого досвіду, але за широкий вжиток не можу казати.

Comment: @P.Vowk, наскільки я можу судити, [правило свердлика](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Правило_гвинта) (a.k.a. [правило правої руки](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Правило_правої_руки) a.k.a. [right-hand rule](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule)) — це цілком конкретне правило, а не загальний вираз для усіх емпіричних правил. І воно навіть не емпіричне за своєю суттю (фактично визначається напрямок векторного добутку). Тобто перетин із [rule of thumb](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_thumb) (a.k.a. [емпіричне правило](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Емпіричне_правило)) фактично нульовий.

Comment: @Sasha для мене правило свердлика в народному вжитку - це саме означник якогось такого зрозумілого правила для вирішення проблем. Я саме це хотів сказати.

Comment: @P.Vowk, не знаю, не зустрічав такого вжитку — але цілком можливо, Ви маєте рацію.

Comment: @Sasha, так, використовувати окрему назву, якщо це буде мати якусь доречність.

Втім, назва "правило свердлика" — це дійсно визначення конкретного правила, а не якесь узагальнення, але якщо така фраза вам підходить, то контекст художнього твору, наприклад, дозволяє зробити з неї власний усталений вираз. До речі, який стиль ви використовуєте?

Comment: Це не моє запитання, це @Yola. Я взяв участь у цьому обговоренні просто з цікавості. Але припускаю, що науково-популярний.

Answer (score -2):

Згідно до словника [Мультитран](https://www.multitran.ru/c/M.exe?CL=1&s=Rule%20of%20thumb&l1=1), а також, якщо перекласти отримані результати в Гугл перекладачі з російської на українську, то ми отримаємо такі варіанти: "перевірене правило", "загальне правило", "правило номер один", "головне правило", "універсальне правило", "перевірений часом метод", тощо.

Comment: -1: незрозуміло, яким чином переклад з англійської на російську може мати бодай яку цінність при перекладі українською.

Comment: Ну все дуже просто, як бачите Гугл Перекладач, та й жодний онлайн перекладач з англійської на російську не може виконати адекватного перекладу, а Мультитран вважається одним з кращих онлайн перекладачів. У ньому є безліч відповідників і завдяки цим відповідникам можна знайти варіанти українського перекладу. Чи на вашу думку в українській мові не може бути жодного з варіантів перелічених мною?

Comment: Re: "Мультитран вважається" — ким вважається? Re: "Чи на вашу думку в українській мові не може бути жодного" — на мою думку, є багато хороших українських джерел, які не потребують перекладу через сторонні мови. Щоб послуговуватися іншомовними словниками, треба мати дуже вагомі аргументи, користь від такого використання перевищувала вади іноземних словників.

Comment: Наведені мною варіанти перекладу можливі і, що важливіше, вживаються в українській мові та можуть підійти для перекладу фразеологізму "a tule of thumb", наприклад: "a useful rule of thumb is that about ten hours will be needed to..." - "перевірене правило: близько десяти годин потрібно, щоб..." (якщо потрібно наведу приклад схожого перекладу, а також вживання наведених мною варіантів). Мета моєї відповіді полягала у тому, щоб дати більше варіантів перекладу даного фразеологізму, яких не дають популярні українські онлайн перекладачів.

Comment: З усією повагою до вас, не бачу сенсу починати суперечку в коментарях, бо все ж таки сайт не для цього створювався)
Якщо хочете можемо з вами обговорити це питання в особистих повідомленнях (якщо вони тут є, звичайно). Я вловив хід ваших думок, тому більше не наводитиму прикладів з даного джерела, але сподіваюся, ви також зрозуміли до чого я веду.